# Combining KnockoutJS special properties with computed functions

Tags: knockout.js

I'm binding a template using a foreach data-binding.  Within the template $index returns a value. Also, a ko.computed function I've written returns a number (the length of the array - 1).  Both numbers appear to be valid, but when I check to see if they are equal, it always returns false.

Code for computed function:

```
this.lastIndex = ko.computed(function () {
    return parent ? parent.whereClauses().length - 1 : 0;
});
```

Code to display the results:

```
<div>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($index, null, 2)"></pre>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(lastIndex, null, 2)"></pre>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($index != lastIndex, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($index, null, 2)">1</pre>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(lastIndex, null, 2)">1</pre>
  <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($index === lastIndex, null, 2)">false</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the functions:

```
<div>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($index(), null, 2)"></pre>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(lastIndex(), null, 2)"></pre>
   <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($index() != lastIndex(), null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

Or else you are comparing function references.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I know that, because I've done that a hand full of times. $index requiring a the function call especially.